# Can I configure network broadcast address on Cisco ASA device

Tags: networking, cisco

Working on Cisco ASA 5510 device I tried to use the broadcast IP address of a Public Network for NAT Static configuration and IOS allowed me to do it, but from outside it didn't work. After a while I changed the broadcast IP to an usable IP and it started to work.
I understand that on a physical interface we can't configured a broadcast IP address, but for NAT we have to do it, otherwise we loose many Public IP addresses from networks with /29 prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need to squeeze one more IP address for you to use, however most routers don't support forwarding broadcast traffic, for a simple fact, if that is allowed, anyone can send a ping to someone's broadcast address and every host in that subnet has to reply, that is not acceptable.
Other Internet routers may not tell that IP address is broadcast or not, but think about your ISP router for your access circuit, it has to know that IP address is a broadcast, it has to know your ip range in order to set it up. And when someone send you a ping, the router will say: hey, that is a broadcast address on my client's interface, first thing I know as a router, I must not forward a broadcast, thus drop it.

Hope it helps.